How to set `org-tag-alist` locally within a function?
I have been reading about the fast tag selection interface in the manual, and I would like to use it, but only in some cases.
When I set tags for some kind of topics grouping, I am fine using the completion minibuffer, I still have too many tags to make a letter selection practical. It also depends a lot on the context; mostly, I am tagging tasks or general notes, the former having far fewer 'topic' tags.
I have however a few tags that I use for maintenance purposes or status indication,like 'DRAFT', 'WIP', 'REFILE', etc... In those cases, the fast selection interface combined for mutually exclusive group tags is exactly what I need.
I would rather not set the TAGS keyword in all of my files (I also use org-roam so I have a lot!), and I am trying to simply keep my settings as is, to invoke the tag completion interface as I always have, and add a custom wrapper function (with a different binding) to bring up the fast tag selection interface with a custom set of tag candidates when I need it.
I have tried to wrap org-set-tags-commands in a let containing the appropriate configuration (using the documentation example for testing), but it is not working:
(let ((org-use-fast-tag-selection t)
      (org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags nil)
      (org-tag-alist '((:startgroup . nil)
                       ("@work" . ?w) ("@home" . ?h)
                       ("@tennisclub" . ?t)
                       (:endgroup . nil)
                       )))
  (org-set-tags-command))

I also tried using org-tag-persistent-alist instead, with the same result. All variables in the let take effect, but the tag list and groups seem to be ignored.
== EDIT ==
The opposite of what I was doing works fine:

Set org-tag-alist globally in the config file
Wrap the following in a function:

(let ((org-use-fast-tag-selection nil)
      (org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags t)
  (org-set-tags-command))

This allows me to achieve more or less what I intended to do, but it does not allow me to assign customized sets of tag candidates under arbitrary conditions.
I will leave the question unanswered in case someone knows a way to achieve that part.

Not sure if it's going to work, but try setting org-current-tag-alist instead of org-tag-alist.

The problem is that org-set-tags-command does not consult either org-tag-alist or org-persistent-tag-alist. Instead, it consults org-current-tag-alist which is constructed out of the other two at buffer initialization time. So try this function instead:
(defun my/org-set-tags-command ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-use-fast-tag-selection t)
        (org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags nil)
        (org-current-tag-alist '((:startgroup . nil)
                                 ("@work" . ?w)
                                 ("@home" . ?h)
                                 ("@tennisclub" . ?t)
                                 (:endgroup . nil)
                                 )))
    (org-set-tags-command)))

BTW, org-current-tag-alist is automatically made buffer-local.

Thank you, it is exactly what I was looking for.
